# "flutter channel master" did something wrong and "flutter" commands do not work anymore. How can I fix this?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, channel, darwin

I am trying to build an app using Android studio.
When building, error as shown in the picture was occurred.
[Error while building the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLV87.jpg)

Error message:

> Because tarantula2 requires SDK version >=2.17.0-265.0.dev <3.0.0, version solving failed.
> pub get failed ...

In the other PC, I used master version of flutter. So I entered "flutter channel master" to change flutter version. And then lots of error occurred as shown in the following image.
[Error after running "flutter channel master" vol. 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRG6u.png)
[Error after running "flutter channel master" vol.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fc6w2.png)

Once it's done, none of commands: "flutter doctor", "flutter channel", "flutter upgrade" does not work anymore.
It says, "no such file", and "Failed to retrieve the Dart SDK". [error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iL9yX.png)

Furthermore, I can't build the app anymore..[no ▶︎ button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4O6N.jpg)

Please let me know if there is a solution.

Comment: In your pubspec.yaml, change this to sdk: '>=2.17.0 <3.0.0'

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Now I can't even build my app anymore.(I added the image at the last of my post.)